Why can't MySQL 8 use a fulltext index with MATCH AGAINST > ? in prepared statement but 5.7 can?
Consider the following SQL:
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FULLTEXT name (first_name, last_name)
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE populate_users()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

    WHILE i <= 100 DO
        INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, created_at, updated_at)
        VALUES (
            CONCAT('FirstName', i),
            CONCAT('LastName', i),
            CONCAT('user', i, '@example.com'),
            'password123',
            NOW(),
            NOW()
        );
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL populate_users();

PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'EXPLAIN SELECT *, MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as search_score FROM users WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0';
SET @a = "FirstName6";
SET @b = "FirstName6";
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

PREPARE stmt2 FROM 'EXPLAIN SELECT *, MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as search_score FROM users WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) > ?';
SET @c = "FirstName6";
SET @d = "FirstName6";
SET @e = 0;
EXECUTE stmt2 USING @c, @d, @e;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

PREPARE stmt3 FROM 'EXPLAIN SELECT *, MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) as search_score FROM users USE INDEX (name) WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE) > ?';
SET @f = "FirstName6";
SET @g = "FirstName6";
SET @h = 0;
EXECUTE stmt3 USING @f, @g, @h;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

The first statement uses the name full-text index, but the second and third don't in MySQL 8. Even when telling the optimizer to use the index, it can't. Why is that?
With MySQL 5.7, all three statements use the index.
The code can be run on https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42e4cteew

Because MySQL's optimization is poor?

Does it use the index with > '0'?  If not, does casting the ? help?

Why are you using fulltext index and fulltext search for names?

It's an example.

Do you want to use any test other than > '0' ?

The query is built dynamically with PHP, and the minimum score is a parameter to the FTS query builder. We're using prepared statements everywhere, and the minimum score was also a variable. Everything worked well with MySQL 5.7 but after upgrading to MySQL 8, we've noticed massive performance problems with all FTS queries. The fix was to inject the minimum score to the SQL query string rather than having it as a bound parameter. So yes, queries can be with > 0 or > 2 etc. I was just wondering what the reason for the change is.
